# Available data in TradingView's exported chart data file

Tags: python, charts, trading, strategy-pattern, tradingview-api

To back-test a trading strategy, I use the replay feature in trading view and mark my trades by adding a "long position" or "short position" from the left panel. Like this:

[image]

I need to save the data (chart data including the positions, or any other drawing I have in that layout) as an Excel or a CSV file on my PC.

I know TradinView has export chart data features but does it include all the positions and the drawings or is it just chart data and the indicators?

If that doesn't work, is there any way to get that data? (from tradingview api for example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like there's only candle and indicator data in the exported file. Nothing related to your positions or drawing.

Here's a sample exported file from BTCUSDT with Ichimoku

[image]: